# Fail before command was complete

Tags: macros, paragraphs

I'd like my new command works even with a multiparagraph or tikz picture as parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,xparse,calc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\HorsListe}{sO{1}m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \par\nopagebreak[4]\addvspace{1\itemsep}%
        \hspace{-#2\leftmargin}}{%
    \par\nopagebreak[4]\addvspace{2\itemsep}%
        \hspace{-#2\leftmargin}}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth+#2\leftmargin}
    #3

    \addvspace{3\itemsep}
    \end{minipage}%
    \nopagebreak[2]}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This works

\HorsListe{Something wide}

\item This doesn't work.

\HorsListe{Something wide

    with paragraph}

\item This doesn't work too

\HorsListe{\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,0) ;

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments of `\NewDocumentCommand` are assumed to be short. You need `+` to make them long:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\HorsListe}{sO{1}+m}{ CODE HERE }
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `+` trick !!!